# How to search JSON using defiantjs - Javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I need to search a large JSON using Javascript. After that I found this library [defiantjs](http://defiantjs.com/). I'm trying to search for a particular product & retrun all those products as response.

For Example:

If I need to search for Shampoo. Then the response should return all the Shampoo products in a JSONArray.

Please guide me whether i should use any other library or this library can do it.

```html
<html>
<head>
  <title>Shopper Search</title>
  <script src="./defiant.min.js" type="text/javascript" /></script>
  <script>
    var data = {
      "Products": {
        "C01M01P001": {
          "productBuyingPrice": "",
          "productCID": "C01",
          "productDescription": "3 Roses Mind Sharp Tea 250 gms..",
          "productID": "C01M01P001",
          "productImage": "http://www.the.com/image/cache/Product_Images/3RosesMindSharp250g-500x500.jpg",
          "productMID": "M01",
          "productMRP": "160.00",
          "productName": "3 Roses Mind Sharp Tea",
          "productSID": "",
          "productSellingPrice": "",
          "productStatus": false,
          "productUnit": "250 gms",
          "wholesalePrice": ""
        },
        "C09M01S01P032": {
          "productBuyingPrice": "",
          "productCID": "C09",
          "productDescription": "Dove Hairfall Rescue Shampoo 180 ml..",
          "productID": "C09M01S01P032",
          "productImage": "http://www.the.com/image/cache/Product_Images_2016/20160517-IMG_4918-500x500.jpg",
          "productMID": "M01",
          "productMRP": "160.00",
          "productName": "Dove Hairfall Rescue Shampoo",
          "productSID": "S01",
          "productSellingPrice": "",
          "productStatus": true,
          "productUnit": "180 ml",
          "wholesalePrice": ""
        },
        "C09M01S01P020": {
          "productBuyingPrice": "",
          "productCID": "C09",
          "productDescription": "Clinic Plus Strong & Long Health Shampoo 30 ml..",
          "productID": "C09M01S01P020",
          "productImage": "http://www.the.com/image/cache/Product_Images_2016/20160525-IMG_5100-500x500.jpg",
          "productMID": "M01",
          "productMRP": "10.00",
          "productName": "Clinic Plus Strong & Long Health Shampoo",
          "productSID": "S01",
          "productSellingPrice": "",
          "productStatus": true,
          "productUnit": "30 ml",
          "wholesalePrice": ""
        },
        "C09M01S03P012": {
          "productBuyingPrice": "",
          "productCID": "C09",
          "productDescription": "Dabur Amla Hair Oil 90 ml..",
          "productID": "C09M01S03P012",
          "productImage": "http://www.the.com/image/cache/Product_Images_2016/daburamlahairoilomi-500x500.jpg",
          "productMID": "M01",
          "productMRP": "42.00",
          "productName": "Dabur Amla Hair Oil",
          "productSID": "S03",
          "productSellingPrice": "",
          "productStatus": true,
          "productUnit": "90 ml",
          "wholesalePrice": ""
        },
        "C09M01S01P102": {
          "productBuyingPrice": "",
          "productCID": "C09",
          "productDescription": "Pantene Shampoo Anti-Dandruff 180 ml..",
          "productID": "C09M01S01P102",
          "productImage": "http://www.the.com/image/cache/Product_Images_2016/20160524-IMG_5051-500x500.jpg",
          "productMID": "M01",
          "productMRP": "155.00",
          "productName": "Pantene Shampoo Anti-Dandruff",
          "productSID": "S01",
          "productSellingPrice": "",
          "productStatus": true,
          "productUnit": "180 ml",
          "wholesalePrice": ""
        },
        "C08M07S01P012": {
          "productBuyingPrice": "",
          "productCID": "C08",
          "productDescription": "Tiger Rose Essence 20 ml..",
          "productID": "C08M07S01P012",
          "productImage": "http://www.the.com/image/cache/Product_Images/1724_tiger-500x500.jpg",
          "productMID": "M07",
          "productMRP": "23.00",
          "productName": "Tiger Rose Essence",
          "productSID": "S01",
          "productSellingPrice": "",
          "productStatus": true,
          "productUnit": "20 ml",
          "wholesalePrice": ""
        },
        "C08M02S01P049": {
          "productBuyingPrice": "",
          "productCID": "C08",
          "productDescription": "Britannia Treat - Jim Jam Biscuits 100 gms..",
          "productID": "C08M02S01P049",
          "productImage": "http://www.the.com/image/cache/Product_Images_2016/treat-jim-jam-500x500.png",
          "productMID": "M02",
          "productMRP": "20.00",
          "productName": "Britannia Treat - Jim Jam Biscuits",
          "productSID": "S01",
          "productSellingPrice": "",
          "productStatus": true,
          "productUnit": "100 gms",
          "wholesalePrice": ""
        },
        "C07M05S01P002": {
          "productBuyingPrice": "",
          "productCID": "C07",
          "productDescription": "Cycle Three in One Agarbathis 138 gms..",
          "productID": "C07M05S01P002",
          "productImage": "http://www.the.com/image/cache/Product_Images_2016/20160314-IMG_8135-500x500.jpg",
          "productMID": "M05",
          "productMRP": "50.00",
          "productName": "Cycle Three in One Agarbathis",
          "productSID": "S01",
          "productSellingPrice": "",
          "productStatus": true,
          "productUnit": "138 gms",
          "wholesalePrice": ""
        },
        "C06M02S01P001": {
          "productBuyingPrice": "",
          "productCID": "C06",
          "productDescription": "Annachi Poo - Star Anise - Phool Chakri 10 gms..",
          "productID": "C06M02S01P001",
          "productImage": "http://www.the.com/image/cache/Product_Images/shutterstock_228810289_anachipoo-500x500.jpg",
          "productMID": "M02",
          "productMRP": "10.00",
          "productName": "Annachi Poo - Star Anise - Phool Chakri (சோம்பு)",
          "productSID": "S01",
          "productSellingPrice": "",
          "productStatus": true,
          "productUnit": "10 gms",
          "wholesalePrice": ""
        },
        "C08M01S01P007": {
          "productBuyingPrice": "",
          "productCID": "C08",
          "productDescription": "Kellogs Chocos Crunchy Bites 390 gms..",
          "productID": "C08M01S01P007",
          "productImage": "http://www.the.com/image/cache/Product_Images/kellogschocoscrunchybites-500x500.jpg",
          "productMID": "M01",
          "productMRP": "165.00",
          "productName": "Kellogg's Chocos Crunchy Bites",
          "productSID": "S01",
          "productSellingPrice": "",
          "productStatus": true,
          "productUnit": "390 gms",
          "wholesalePrice": ""
        }
      }
    };

    var snapshot = Defiant.getSnapshot(data);
    // Snapshot search - this is more than 100 times faster than 'regular search'
    // //*/productName["Star"]/productName
    found = JSON.search(snapshot, '//*productName["shampoo"]');

    console.log(found);
  </script>
</head>

<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Xpath `contains`

```
var data = {
      "Products": {
        "C01M01P001": {
          "productBuyingPrice": "",
          "productCID": "C01",
          "productDescription": "3 Roses Mind Sharp Tea 250 gms..",
          "productID": "C01M01P001",
          "productImage": "http://www.the.com/image/cache/Product_Images/3RosesMindSharp250g-500x500.jpg",
          "productMID": "M01",
          "productMRP": "160.00",
          "productName": "3 Roses Mind Sharp Tea",
          "productSID": "",
          "productSellingPrice": "",
          "productStatus": false,
          "productUnit": "250 gms",
          "wholesalePrice": ""
        },
        "C09M01S01P032": {
          "productBuyingPrice": "",
          "productCID": "C09",
          "productDescription": "Dove Hairfall Rescue Shampoo 180 ml..",
          "productID": "C09M01S01P032",
          "productImage": "http://www.the.com/image/cache/Product_Images_2016/20160517-IMG_4918-500x500.jpg",
          "productMID": "M01",
          "productMRP": "160.00",
          "productName": "Dove Hairfall Rescue Shampoo",
          "productSID": "S01",
          "productSellingPrice": "",
          "productStatus": true,
          "productUnit": "180 ml",
          "wholesalePrice": ""
        },
        "C09M01S01P020": {
          "productBuyingPrice": "",
          "productCID": "C09",
          "productDescription": "Clinic Plus Strong & Long Health Shampoo 30 ml..",
          "productID": "C09M01S01P020",
          "productImage": "http://www.the.com/image/cache/Product_Images_2016/20160525-IMG_5100-500x500.jpg",
          "productMID": "M01",
          "productMRP": "10.00",
          "productName": "Clinic Plus Strong & Long Health Shampoo",
          "productSID": "S01",
          "productSellingPrice": "",
          "productStatus": true,
          "productUnit": "30 ml",
          "wholesalePrice": ""
        },
        "C09M01S03P012": {
          "productBuyingPrice": "",
          "productCID": "C09",
          "productDescription": "Dabur Amla Hair Oil 90 ml..",
          "productID": "C09M01S03P012",
          "productImage": "http://www.the.com/image/cache/Product_Images_2016/daburamlahairoilomi-500x500.jpg",
          "productMID": "M01",
          "productMRP": "42.00",
          "productName": "Dabur Amla Hair Oil",
          "productSID": "S03",
          "productSellingPrice": "",
          "productStatus": true,
          "productUnit": "90 ml",
          "wholesalePrice": ""
        },
        "C09M01S01P102": {
          "productBuyingPrice": "",
          "productCID": "C09",
          "productDescription": "Pantene Shampoo Anti-Dandruff 180 ml..",
          "productID": "C09M01S01P102",
          "productImage": "http://www.the.com/image/cache/Product_Images_2016/20160524-IMG_5051-500x500.jpg",
          "productMID": "M01",
          "productMRP": "155.00",
          "productName": "Pantene Shampoo Anti-Dandruff",
          "productSID": "S01",
          "productSellingPrice": "",
          "productStatus": true,
          "productUnit": "180 ml",
          "wholesalePrice": ""
        },
        "C08M07S01P012": {
          "productBuyingPrice": "",
          "productCID": "C08",
          "productDescription": "Tiger Rose Essence 20 ml..",
          "productID": "C08M07S01P012",
          "productImage": "http://www.the.com/image/cache/Product_Images/1724_tiger-500x500.jpg",
          "productMID": "M07",
          "productMRP": "23.00",
          "productName": "Tiger Rose Essence",
          "productSID": "S01",
          "productSellingPrice": "",
          "productStatus": true,
          "productUnit": "20 ml",
          "wholesalePrice": ""
        },
        "C08M02S01P049": {
          "productBuyingPrice": "",
          "productCID": "C08",
          "productDescription": "Britannia Treat - Jim Jam Biscuits 100 gms..",
          "productID": "C08M02S01P049",
          "productImage": "http://www.the.com/image/cache/Product_Images_2016/treat-jim-jam-500x500.png",
          "productMID": "M02",
          "productMRP": "20.00",
          "productName": "Britannia Treat - Jim Jam Biscuits",
          "productSID": "S01",
          "productSellingPrice": "",
          "productStatus": true,
          "productUnit": "100 gms",
          "wholesalePrice": ""
        },
        "C07M05S01P002": {
          "productBuyingPrice": "",
          "productCID": "C07",
          "productDescription": "Cycle Three in One Agarbathis 138 gms..",
          "productID": "C07M05S01P002",
          "productImage": "http://www.the.com/image/cache/Product_Images_2016/20160314-IMG_8135-500x500.jpg",
          "productMID": "M05",
          "productMRP": "50.00",
          "productName": "Cycle Three in One Agarbathis",
          "productSID": "S01",
          "productSellingPrice": "",
          "productStatus": true,
          "productUnit": "138 gms",
          "wholesalePrice": ""
        },
        "C06M02S01P001": {
          "productBuyingPrice": "",
          "productCID": "C06",
          "productDescription": "Annachi Poo - Star Anise - Phool Chakri 10 gms..",
          "productID": "C06M02S01P001",
          "productImage": "http://www.the.com/image/cache/Product_Images/shutterstock_228810289_anachipoo-500x500.jpg",
          "productMID": "M02",
          "productMRP": "10.00",
          "productName": "Annachi Poo - Star Anise - Phool Chakri (சோம்பு)",
          "productSID": "S01",
          "productSellingPrice": "",
          "productStatus": true,
          "productUnit": "10 gms",
          "wholesalePrice": ""
        },
        "C08M01S01P007": {
          "productBuyingPrice": "",
          "productCID": "C08",
          "productDescription": "Kellogs Chocos Crunchy Bites 390 gms..",
          "productID": "C08M01S01P007",
          "productImage": "http://www.the.com/image/cache/Product_Images/kellogschocoscrunchybites-500x500.jpg",
          "productMID": "M01",
          "productMRP": "165.00",
          "productName": "Kellogg's Chocos Crunchy Bites",
          "productSID": "S01",
          "productSellingPrice": "",
          "productStatus": true,
          "productUnit": "390 gms",
          "wholesalePrice": ""
        }
      }
    };
    var productNames = JSON.search(data,'//productName[contains(text(),"Shampoo")]');
    console.log('Data ::'+productNames);
```

Output is :

```
Data ::Dove Hairfall Rescue Shampoo,Clinic Plus Strong &amp; Long Health Shampoo,Pantene Shampoo Anti-Dandruff
```

Comment: The output shows only the productName. But how can I return all those 3 JSONobjects in a single Jsonarray ?